# how can I print out the Retail price and the Cost price of a product in django oscar?

Tags: django, django-oscar

In django oscar when creating a product in stock and pricing step there are options ( Cost Price , Price (excl tax) , Retail price )
the Price (excl tax) is the price is showing on the product view 
how can I show the retail or the cost price alongside the Price (excl tax) ?

my desire is to make an old price and new one
like 100$ down from 300$
I want to use the existing product form to fulfill this task
I mean the 100$ be in the retail or cost price and then I print it in the product template alongside the Price(excl tax)
how can I print it ?

Comment: can you show what have you done ?

Comment: I haven't done any thing yet, django-oscar framework already has these fields ( Cost Price , Price (excl tax) , Retail price ) , I just wanna show them into my product template , I mean like this `{{ price.excl_tax }}` this one used in the product template to show the price , I wanna know if there is something similar to show the retail and cost price

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out , I can use `{{ stockrecord.cost_price }}` and `{{ stockrecord.price_retail }}` to handle this task :)